# Idiomatically parsing a whitespace-separated string into a Vec of tuples of differing types

Tags: vector, iterator, rust

I have a struct `EnclosingObject` which contains a field of a `Vec` of tuples. I want to implement `FromStr` for this struct in a way that an `EnclosingObject` can be parsed from a string with the following structure: `<number of tuples> <tuple1 str1> <tuple1 str2> <tuple1 i32> <tuple2 str1> <tuple2 str2>` ...

This is what I have come up with so far (ignoring the case of an invalid number of tuples):

```
use std::str::FromStr;
use std::num::ParseIntError;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct EnclosingObject{
    tuples: Vec<(String, String, i32)>,
}

impl FromStr for EnclosingObject {
    type Err = ParseIntError;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        let elems_vec = s.split_whitespace().collect::<Vec<_>>();
        let mut elems = elems_vec.as_slice();

        let num_tuples = elems[0].parse::<usize>()?;
        elems = &elems[1..];
        let mut tuples = Vec::with_capacity(num_tuples);
        for chunk in elems.chunks(3).take(num_tuples){
            tuples.push((chunk[0].into(),
                    chunk[1].into(),
                    chunk[2].parse::<i32>()?));
        }

        Ok(EnclosingObject{
            tuples : tuples
        })
    }
}

fn main(){  
    println!("{:?}", EnclosingObject::from_str("3 a b 42 c d 32 e f 50"));  
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e34a361ee7750e33bb0ff90c75e9dd52&version=stable))

As expected, for a valid string it prints out:

```
Ok(EnclosingObject { tuples: [("a", "b", 42), ("c", "d", 32), ("e", "f", 50)] })
```

and for an invalid string e.g. "3 a b x c d 32 e f 50":

```
Err(ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit })
```

Can I parse this `Vec` of tuples in a more elegant/idiomatic way, such as by using iterators?

I tried a combination of `map` and `collect`, but the problem with this is the error handling:

```
let tuples = elems
            .chunks(3)
            .take(num_tuples)
            .map(|chunk| (chunk[0].into(),
                    chunk[1].into(),
                    chunk[2].parse::<i32>()?))
            .collect();
```

The questionmark-operator seems not to work in this context (within the tuple). So I transformed it a bit:

```
let tuples = try!(elems
            .chunks(3)
            .take(num_tuples)
            .map(|chunk| {
                    let integer = chunk[2].parse::<i32>()?;
                    Ok((chunk[0].into(),
                    chunk[1].into(),
                    integer))})
            .collect());
```

... which works, but again appears a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Considering that you have working code, the question might be more suitable for [Code Review SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: [One possible approach](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=de697ed924eba97b96e8e705b31ca8b2&version=stable). Personally, though, I like your version (with the loop) better. Just because you *can* write code in a functional style, doesn't mean you *should*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The questionmark-operator seems not to work in this context (within the tuple).

The problem is that `?` returns an `Err` in case of failure and you weren't returning an `Ok` in case of success. The operator works just fine if you do that. Beyond that, you can avoid the extraneous allocation of the `Vec` by operating on the iterator from splitting on whitespace:

```
fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
    let mut elems = s.split_whitespace();

    let num_tuples = elems.next().expect("error handling: count missing").parse()?;
    let tuples: Vec<_> = elems
        .by_ref()
        .tuples()
        .map(|(a, b, c)| Ok((a.into(), b.into(), c.parse()?)))
        .take(num_tuples)
        .collect::<Result<_, _>>()?;

    if tuples.len() != num_tuples { panic!("error handling: too few") }
    if elems.next().is_some() { panic!("error handling: too many") }

    Ok(EnclosingObject { tuples })
}
```

I've also used Itertools' `tuples` method which automatically groups an iterator into tuples and collected into a `Result<Vec<_>, _>`. I reduced the redundant `tuples: tuples` in the struct and added some placeholders for the remainder of the error handling. I removed the `Vec::with_capacity` because I trust that the `size_hint` set by `take` will be good enough. If you didn't trust it, you could still use `with_capacity` and then `extend` the vector with the iterator.

Comment: Nitpicking: if `tuples.len() != num_tuples`, it might mean too many as well as too few

Comment: @Jmb how so? Doesn't the `take` prevent that case?

Comment: you're right, I missed the `take`, sorry for the noise